# Why can't I connect my UITextView to my .m file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I just made a `UITextView` and added it to my header file, and synthesized it in my .m file. Now I am trying to make a `UILabel` update every time a character is added to the `UITextView`, but it just doesn't work.

I used the code:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:startTyping{
    _viewTyping.text = _startTyping.text;
}
```

My `UITextView` 'startTying' allow me to type in it, but the `UILabel`, `_viewTyping`, never updates. Any thoughts?

BTW, I also tried the same command using IBAction, but for some reason I can't connect the `UITextView` anywhere is my .m file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UITextView` delegate method:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
      _viewTyping.text = _startTyping.text;
}
```

Did you set the delegate to self?

First declare the delegate:

```
@interface YourViewController ()<UITextViewDelegate>
```

Second set to self

```
 self.textView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Also make sure that your textView's delegate is your .m file, so the message gets sent.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answers... I'm a novice and trying to keep up: how do I 1) set delegate to self, and 2) make sure my textView's delegate is my .m file?

Comment: @interface YourViewController ()<UITextViewDelegate>

Comment: self.textView.delegate = self;

Comment: Put self.textView.delegate = self; in viewDidLoad

Comment: Thanks so much for taking care of my noob questions, it works great!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried both the delegate methods of UITextView both are working

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    _viewTyping.text=textView.text;
    return YES;
}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    _viewTyping.text=textView.text;
}
```

First Delegate function updates the label one character latter. And the second one updates as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use `_viewTyping`? Shouldn't it be `self.viewTyping`?

Also, check if it is nil. It probably is.